# Intellij formatting. Break method with different indent than body

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

How to set the formatter to achieve this formatting:

**before**

```
List<Person> getPersonsByFilters(final UUID personId, final Filter filter) throws NotFoundException {
    //logic    
}
```

**after**

```
List<Person> getPersonsByFilters(final UUID personId, 
        final Filter filter) throws NotFoundException {
    //logic    
}
```

After method definition line break I want to have a bigger indent (`+4`) than method body.

Comment: Personal opinion, but your "after" is more difficult to read. (Maybe I've just spent too long reading code formatted by [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)).

Comment: In this case yes, but when we have more parameters and exceptions it is not

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> - <kbd>Editor</kbd> - <kbd>Code Style</kbd> - <kbd>Java</kbd> - <kbd>Wrapping and Braces</kbd>.
2. Set the option "Wrap if long".
3. Untick the box "Align when multiline".

[image]

Before:

[image]
[image]

After:

[image]

---

EDIT:

I've got "continuation indent" set to `8` (the default value). It might help.

[image]

Comment: I have this option already set as you described. But still It wraps new line in the same indent as body

Comment: @ByeBye, I'll double-check it, another option might be involved

Comment: Yeah, it is working. But it is formatting all code like that. I need that only for a specific situation - method definition break. I often format my code that I am calling method `personService.add(\nid,\nperson\n)` and want to have ident 4. But it will put 8